# meaning of "at baseline"

Tags: meaning

[From the Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/baseline)

> baseline: an imaginary line used as a starting point for making comparisons

[NESDO](https://bmcresnotes.biomedcentral.com/articles/10.1186/1756-0500-4-524) which stands for the Netherlands Study of Depression in Older Persons, is a research program about major depressive disorder. Here is part of its description.

> The NESDO sample consisted, **at baseline**, of 510 participants aged 60–93 years, with a diagnosis present in the preceding 6 months of a depressive disorder (378 of 510) or no history of depressive or anxiety disorders (132 of 510). Recruitment took place in primary health care (response rate of 64%) and in both outpatient and inpatient mental health-care facilities (49%).

without "at baseline", the sentence seems more coherent

> The NESDO sample consisted of 510 participants ...

I understand the meaning of "baseline", according to the quote at the beginning.

What the meaning of "at baseline" there?

Comment: It means at the start; the beginning of the study.

Comment: The definition from Cambridge is not far off, but it is _not_ imaginary in your NESDO excerpt. Perhaps this definition from [Webster's Medical](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/baseline#medicalDictionary) will help you.

Comment: @Wehage Your link is very helpful, thank you! Does "not far off" imply that the definition from Cambridge is close to the actual meaning in the NESDO description?

Comment: @PutBere Yes, "not far off" means close, but not exact. I meant to suggest that `"[...] used as a starting point for making comparisons" (Cambridge)` and `"[...] used for comparison or a control" (Webster's Medical)` are similar in description.

Answer (score 1):

In this study, they had the 510 “baseline participants” take an assessment (the “baseline assessment included written questionnaires, interviews, a medical examination, cognitive tests and collection of blood and saliva samples”).

Saying “baseline participants” is just a convenient way to refer to all the people who took the baseline assessment.

But why specify a baseline? There’s more to this study, because “[f]ollow up assessments are currently going on with 6 monthly written questionnaires and face-to-face interviews after 2 and 6 years”. While there may be 510 baseline participants, not all of them are expected to stick around for the entirety of the research, either because they changed their mind, can’t be found, or sadly passed away. (It also makes it clear that the count does not include any of the people that they filtered out in previous steps, such as those that were approached and didn’t want to participate in the research.)

Comment: Thanks for your comprehensive explanation for why research needs a baseline. Would you please explain a little bit more about whether the meaning changes or not when omitting "at baseline" in the quoted research paper?

Comment: @PutBere It becomes less clear who exactly the count includes if you omit “at baseline”, although I think you can still figure it out with some effort if you look at the rest of the paper.

Comment: Thank you. So, "at baseline" is to clearly indicate those 510 participants are "baseline participants", right?